# Pasar valor de combobox en SQL query para llenar segundo combobox

Tags: javafx

mi problema es el siguiente, tengo dos métodos, en el primer método lleno un combobox con datos de una tabla de una base de datos, ese método funciona muy bien, mostrándome todos los registros que inserto en el combobox#1, por lo cual deseo pasar a través del combobox#1 el valor del String seleccionado en este y luego pasarlo  para llenar  el combobox#2, para ello tengo un Query en el segundo método, en donde  capturo el valor del primer combobox para llenar el segundo, pero no he tenido éxito, el valor se muestra vació, no se si estoy haciendo mal la referencia o no.

acá les dejo el código para que me orienten.

```
public void llenadocombobox2() {
        Connection conn=null;
        try {
            ObservableList<String> listacombonombre= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            String consulta = "select nombre from entidad";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-4JA6SFR:1433;databaseName=GLOSASNINO", "sa", "123");
            PreparedStatement ps =conn.prepareStatement(consulta);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
             while ( rs.next() ) 
             {  
               listacombonombre.add(rs.getString("nombre"));
             }
          entidad.setItems(listacombonombre);  
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public void llenadocombobox3() {
        String DatoCombo2= entidad.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        Connection conn=null;
        try {
            ObservableList<String> listacombonit= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            String consulta = "select nit from entidad where nombre='"+DatoCombo2+"'";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-4JA6SFR:1433;databaseName=GLOSASNINO", "sa", "123");
            PreparedStatement ps =conn.prepareStatement(consulta);
             ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
             while ( rs.next() ) 
             {  
               listacombonit.add(rs.getString("nit"));
             }

          nit.setItems(listacombonit);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       llenadocombobox2();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para el ComboBox no es necesario

```
ObservableList<String> listacombonombre= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Este es una manera simple de poder agregar valores dinamicamente

```
patrones.getItems().addAll("XML Clientes -> MMAA_RfcReceptor_Folio+Serie_sociedad(RfcEmisor)_Importe",
                               "XML Proveedores -> MMAA_RfcEmisor_Folio+Serie+_sociedad(RfcReceptor)_Importe",
                               "XML Complementos -> COPAPRO_MMAA_RfcEmisor_sociedad(RfcReceptor)_Importe",
                               "XML SAT -> revisar"
                               );
```

Modificalo y usalo según tus requerimientos.